# Cumulative sum over ImageCollection with values stored for each iteration

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have indexed for water cover using summertime Landsat8 images, and have reduced the ImageCollection to a single image per year indicating whether a surface has been covered or not (0 or 1). I would like to perform a cumulative sum for each year on record to get a yearly timeseries for when pixels were covered by water. I would like to store each iteration as a band in an Image for simple export, such that band0 = year(1); band1 = band(0) + year (2); band2 = band(1) + year (3) etc, before exporting the image using Export.image.toDrive().

```
var ic = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_RT_TOA")
      .filterDate('2013-06-01', '2023-09-01');

// A polygon representing the roi. (geometry)

var c = ic.filterBounds(geometry);

var withCloudiness = c.map(function(image) {
  var cloud = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select('cloud');
  var cloudiness = cloud.reduceRegion({
    reducer: 'mean', 
    geometry: geometry, 
    scale: 30,
  });
  return image.set(cloudiness);
});

var filteredCollection = withCloudiness.filter(ee.Filter.lt('cloud', 20));

// Filter images between June and August
var juneToAugust = filteredCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6, 8, 'month'));
print('Summer image collection',juneToAugust);

// Clip to geometry
var clip_func = function(img){
  // image collection clip loop
  return img.clip(geometry)
} 
var clipped_Lawei = juneToAugust.map(clip_func)
print('Retrievals clipped to geometry',clipped_Lawei)

// Compute water cover index with two indexes
var getAWEI_nsh = function(img){
  return img.addBands(img.expression(
    '4 * ((GRN - SWIR1) - (0.25 * NIR + 2.75 * SWIR2))', {
      'GRN': img.select('B3'),
      'NIR': img.select('B5'),
      'SWIR1': img.select('B6'),
      'SWIR2': img.select('B7')
}).rename('AWEI_nsh'));
};

var getAWEI_sh = function(img){
  return img.addBands(img.expression(
    'BLU + 2.5 * GRN - 1.5 * (NIR + SWIR1) - 0.25 * SWIR2', {
      'BLU': img.select('B2'),
      'GRN': img.select('B3'),
      'NIR': img.select('B5'),
      'SWIR1': img.select('B6'),
      'SWIR2': img.select('B7')
}).rename('AWEI_sh'));
};

// combine both AWEI into 1 image collection
var tmp = clipped_Lawei.map(getAWEI_nsh);
var Lawei = tmp.map(getAWEI_sh); // has both AWEI indexess
print('Clipped retrievals with both AWEI index',Lawei);

// Combine two indexes sequentially: where both are >0.
var bandExp1 = '(b("AWEI_nsh") > 0)'; // don't return zeros as previously 
var bandExp2 = '(b("AWEI_sh") > 0)'; // don't return zeros as previously 
// Create function() to apply index on every image in the collection (AWEI_nsh > 0 && AWEI_sh > 0)
var index_func = function(img){
  return img.addBands(img.expression(bandExp1).and(img.expression(bandExp2)).rename("AWEI_corrected")); 
} ;
var awei_water = Lawei.map(index_func);
print('Retrievals with AWEI - "awei_water"',awei_water)

awei_water = awei_water.select('AWEI_corrected') // just take true/false index

// Ascertain whether for all images in summer, pixels were water or not (find max value across the images): 0 or 1)
var startYear = 2013;
var endYear = 2023;
var years = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear);

// Function to reduce images for a specific year
var reduceForYear = function(year) {
  var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 6, 1);
  var end = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 8, 31);
  var yearImages = awei_water.filterDate(start, end);
  var reduced = yearImages.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
  return reduced.set('year', year);
};

// Map over the list of years and reduce images for each year
var reducedCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(years.map(reduceForYear));
print('Reduced Collection', reducedCollection)

// successfully reduced to single annual summertime max (covered by water or not)

// Get cumulative count, i.e. band0 = year(1); band1 = year(1) + year (2); band2 = year(1) + year (2) + year (3) etc.
// Unsure how to proceed

var n = ee.List.sequence(0,19);
var col = reducedCollection ; 
function compare(i){
  var imgA = ee.Image(col.get(i));
  var imgB = ee.Image(col.get(ee.Number(1).add(i)));
  return imgA.select('AWEI_corrected_max').add(imgB.select('AWEI_corrected_max'));
}

var result = ee.ImageCollection(n.map(compare).flatten());
print('result',result)
```